# Changing video source javascript

Tags: javascript

My solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/g7mrs/22/

```
function loadVideo(event) {
  videojs("myPlayer").src({ 
    type: "video/youtube",
    src: "https://youtu.be/ZSn3Tvc7jQU"
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

I got a working solution, however I would like to have only 1 function instead of 4

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp
or you can use `data-src` attribute on button, and get it with: `event.target.dataset.src`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass YouTube URL as a parameter:

```
function loadVideo(url) {
    videojs("myPlayer").src({ type: "video/youtube", src: url});
    event.preventDefault();                  
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="loadVideo('https://youtu.be/ZSn3Tvc7jQU')">video</a>
<a href="#" onClick="loadVideo('https://youtu.be/0BhSrfNgLxs')">video2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @hsz answer, You can also add the first part of the url to the function, and just send the ID.

This will also help if you need to later on change your video provider, since you only will have to change the base (assuming that the id stays the same).

> So your JS function:

```
var base = 'https://youtu.be/';

function loadVideo(id) {
    videojs("myPlayer").src({ type: "video/youtube", src: base + id });
    event.preventDefault();                  
}
```

> end then in the HTML

```
<a href="#" onClick="loadVideo('ZSn3Tvc7jQU')">video</a>
```